# RedrawWindow API does not force the MDI child repaint in MDI applicaiton

Tags: windows, winapi, mdi

I am trying to use the Windows API function `RedrawWindow` to force a window to repaint.

This is working perfectly for almost all applications, but it does not work for a legacy MDI application. It repaints the parent (host) window, but not the MDI child window.

Does anyone know about this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your code.

Answer (score 1):

RedrawWindow applies to one window only, so you are probably calling it with the wrong HWND. So you will need to find the correct HWND for the child window.

Comment: For sure that I specified correct window. It does not repaint even I use API Monitor tool (rohitab.com). This is the application I am facing issue : http://www.csledger.com/download.html. I guess it is a legacy Foxpro application. I have no idea if Foxpro MDI application cause of this issue.